# SSD SMART failing - two temperature values?

Tags: ssd, smart

Running Ubuntu 12.04. This morning I started getting disk failure warnings on my root drive (EDGE™ Boost Pro Plus 7mm SSD 240GB).

Looking at the SMART data shows the failing attribute is 231 Temperature, with a value of 1C (obviously wrong). Weird thing is ID 194 is also Temperature, and seems correct (this value is also shown as the temperature in the SMART Data window.

Is this likely to reflect a real hardware failure? Should I try to get a warranty replacement?

And if not, is there a simple way to get Ubuntu to ignore this attribute of the SMART data? I'd prefer not to disable SMART warnings completely.

EDIT: results of smartctl below

```
smartctl 5.41 2011-06-09 r3365 [x86_64-linux-3.11.0-15-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-11 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     EDGE Boost Pro 7mm SSD
Serial Number:    ED140408AS1326965
LU WWN Device Id: 0 000120 000000000
Firmware Version: 541ABBF0
User Capacity:    240,057,409,536 bytes [240 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   8
ATA Standard is:  ACS-2 revision 3
Local Time is:    Thu Dec 11 09:53:48 2014 EST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: FAILED!
Drive failure expected in less than 24 hours. SAVE ALL DATA.
See vendor-specific Attribute list for failed Attributes.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x05) Offline data collection activity
                    was aborted by an interrupting command from host.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (  25) The self-test routine was aborted by
                    the host.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x79) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    No Auto Offline data collection support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  48) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x0025) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x0032   095   095   050    Old_age   Always       -       37836672
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   091   091   003    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   096   096   000    Old_age   Always       -       83159156789007
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       35
171 Unknown_Attribute       0x000a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
174 Unknown_Attribute       0x0030   000   000   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
177 Wear_Leveling_Count     0x0000   000   000   000    Old_age   Offline      -       99
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x000a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count_Total  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0012   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0000   029   041   000    Old_age   Offline      -       29 (Min/Max 18/41)
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   029   041   000    Old_age   Always       -       29 (Min/Max 18/41)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x001c   120   120   000    Old_age   Offline      -       37836672
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0033   100   100   003    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
201 Soft_Read_Error_Rate    0x001c   120   120   000    Old_age   Offline      -       37836672
204 Soft_ECC_Correction     0x001c   120   120   000    Old_age   Offline      -       37836672
230 Head_Amplitude          0x0013   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       100
231 Temperature_Celsius     0x0013   001   001   010    Pre-fail  Always   FAILING_NOW 68719476737
233 Media_Wearout_Indicator 0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       5891
234 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log not supported
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Aborted by host               90%      3853         -
# 2  Extended offline    Aborted by host               10%      1990         -
# 3  Conveyance offline  Aborted by host               90%      1990         -
# 4  Short offline       Aborted by host               90%      1990         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: 1) Did you install the latest firmware for your drive? 2) What tool are you using to check the SMART values now? ('Disks' perhaps?) 3) Please provide some additional information on what you see exactly. 4) Please include a full raw dump of the SMART attributes/values, e.g. `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda` to get a better picture on what's going on.

Comment: SMART attribute 231 set to 1 is usually indicating the end of the lifetime of an SSD. Most manufacturers are using this field to indicate the cells are used past the design cycles. Google for 'ssd smart attribute 231'. I think it may be a bug of Ubuntu to show this attribute as a temperature field.

Comment: thanks, sounds like I should probably backup and try to RMA then.

Comment: Please be aware that your data is already corrupt now when reading from the drive. Your hardware/software ECC errors are significantly high. I hope you have a way to validate your data retrieved, otherwise it will be hard to tell what has been damaged. I had this before once on an OCZ SSD, found traces of data corruption back to 60 days prior to SSD failure in the incremental backups. Not funny. Also note that most manufacturers don't accept RMA when this attribute was set because of too many data written to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SMART attribute 231 for an SSD does not indicate anything regarding a temperature. In fact, if the normalized value is something < 2 is usually indicating the end of the lifetime of an SSD (for this attribute high value means better). Most manufacturers are using this field to indicate the cells are used past the design cycles.

Based on the [Wikipedia article on SMART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.#Known_ATA_S.M.A.R.T._attributes) I think this attribute has an ambiguous meaning.

> ```
> 231 | 0xE7 | Temperature   | Drive Temperature
> 231 | 0xE7 | SSD Life Left | Indicates the approximate SSD life left, in terms of
>                              program/erase cycles or Flash blocks currently
>                              available for use.
> ```

I think it may be a bug of Ubuntu to show this attribute as a temperature field for an SSD. Please try 14.04/14.10 from a live image and see if it still shows it as such. If so, please [report it as a bug](https://askubuntu.com/q/5121/88802).

Here's what manufacturers are using in their documentation:

[Seagate](http://www.seagate.com/www-content/product-content/ssd-fam/600-pro-ssd/en-us/docs/100727924b.pdf)

> Limited Warranty with Media Usage provides coverage for the warranty period or until the estimated life indicator reaches 1 as reported by SMART attribute 231.

[Kingston](http://media.kingston.com/support/downloads/MKP_306_SMART_attribute.pdf)

> 231 SSD Life Left
>
> [...]
>
> **Normalized Value Range:**
>
> 100 = Best = Full SSD life remains 
>  
>   1 = Worst = Insufficient Flash blocks remain in service for proper
>   SSD operation

Comment: There's a bug report about this problem against libatasmart: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libatasmart/+bug/1581594

Comment: is there some way to let it (smart data and psensor) to use the id=194 (that shows coherent temperature) and ignore id=231? I have this problem on ubuntu 20.04 and this seems a really old problem. `smartctl` informs properly "231 SSD_Life_Left           0x0000   099   099   000    Old_age   Offline      -       99" but the application Disks and psensors both use the wrong id!

Comment: @AquariusPower you can have your own device database file ([`drivedb.h`](https://github.com/smartmontools/smartmontools/blob/master/smartmontools/drivedb.h)) with `smartctl` (`--drivedb=` option). Takes a bit of time to figure out how to match the right device in it and apply your rules. Look at [the manpage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/smartctl.8.html) of that option for more information.